# Rotation boundary condition Abaqus

Tags: dynamic, implicit, bc, coupling, abaqus

I am trying to create a model which requires me to rotate a part about a certain point. I am running a dynamic implicit simulation.

[image]

As can be seen in the pic, I have created a ref point and created a kinematic coupling with the part. Now when I rotate the part by applying the BC (disp/rotation or angular vel) at the ref point, I see that the volume of the part increases (Can be seen in the pic )

[image]

The deformation scale factor is set to 1 but still I see this significant increase in volume. I don't understand what is causing it and how do I avoid it. What's the correct way to model it?

[image]

Comment: Have you constrained the 'z' displacement? It could be moving in z and so look bigger due to perspective. That would be obvious of course if you just rotate the figure.

Comment: yeah I have checked that. The boundary condition is applied with 0 displacement for all three directions and the two rotational dofs about x and y axes are also restricted to 0. The only motion applied is rotation about z axis. The volume is seen increasing with only rotation though. When I apply just translational motion, this is not observed.

Comment: have you specified nonlinear geometry? what quantity are you plotting there? how many increments?

Comment: Yeah, I think the issue was with me not specifying the nonlinear geometry. It is working as expected when I specify non linear geom. Thanks